# jquery - clone table, first 10 columns only

Tags: jquery

I am trying to clone a table, but I don't want the all the columns. I just want the first 10, is this possible?

```
var tbl = $('#red-blue-table').clone();
```

Comment: Safe to assume you are trying to avoid the `loop...delete` option?

Comment: yea, if I could, that would be awesome